Getting error while reading message from AWS kafka topic
/workspace/source/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server b-2.mbnmskclustersi.whjxra.c13.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9096,b-1.mbnmskclustersi.whjxra.c13.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9096 --topic mbn-to-ens-notification --from-beginning

[2024-04-30 20:14:51,039] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-49176] Bootstrap broker b-1.mbnmskclustersi.whjxra.c13.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9096 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)


I'd recommend to add more details on client config, env vars related to Kafka, etc... for better analysis of the root cause.
But, from what I can see in the CLI sample in the question, you are using SASL-SCRAM (port 9096), but you don't provide any client config that would define security protocol, SASL-SCRAM JAAS config, and other.
Check the documentation and if that doesn't work, give us more details on what you try, and what errors you are getting.
In short, you need to create (for example) client-scram.properties file with the following content:
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="username" password="password";

Then, when you run CLI, add this file as a consumer config:
/workspace/source/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --bootstrap-server b-2.mbnmskclustersi.whjxra.c13.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9096,b-1.mbnmskclustersi.whjxra.c13.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9096 \
  --topic mbn-to-ens-notification \
  --from-beginning \
  --consumer.config <path_to>/client-scram.properties


Why are you posting answers to posts which do not even include a question? Downvote, VTC, move on.

I disagree. It's poorly formed question, without explicit question mark, but is clear.
